# How is the charge of a (heavy) nucleus determined experimentally

Tags: nuclear-physics

Ridding an atom of all of its electrons may be a good idea to measure the charge of its nucleus but I don't know whether it is applicable for heavy nuclei or it is the only way. Could you please explain in some detail how is that done or at least give a hint, or mention some reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fully stripped ions are not that hard to make.

Comment: @JonCuster Reference please ?

Comment: https://www.rhichome.bnl.gov/AP/ap_notes/ap_note_293.pdf To start. Ion beams have been around a long time...

Comment: Thanks a lot!, but for the question, is stripping atoms completely the only way to measure the charge of their nuclei ? as far as you (or any one reading the question) know(s)

Comment: Well, spectroscopy of a neutral atom gives lots of info.